# Selection of jobs based on queue priority

Tags: mathematical-modeling, operations-research

I have a set of workers $P$ and a set of jobs $I$. I'm evaluating the queue priority at every time interval $T$ and the worker will take the job with the highest priority. The priority is calculated based on arrival time, predetermined constants and etc and noted as $Q_i$ at time $t$.

How can I model this so that worker $p_1$ will take the job with the highest $Q_i$ and $p_2$ will take the second highest, and so on?

I know I have to create a binary variable that is $1$ if worker $p$ selects job $i$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a math problem.  I don't understand what it has to do with any of the tags.  Perhaps you could give some more context.  Are you talking about a physical queue and workers?  Is this a computer program?  What do you mean by "make sure?"

Comment: @saulspatz How is this not a math problem? The task here is to model something mathematically, even if perhaps it is not described very well.

Comment: After your edit it sounds more like a math problem to me.  Still, there doesn't seem to be enough information to even begin to answer the question, so far as I can see.  It needs a lot more context.

Comment: Do you know for sure you have to use linear programming?

Answer (score 0):

If $x_{wjt}$ is a binary variable taking value 1 if worker $w$ takes job $j$ at time $t$ and zero otherwise, then $\pi_{wt}=\sum_j Q_j x_{wjt}$ gives you the priority of the job worker $w$ snags at time $t$ (0 if the worker does not take any job). So you want $\pi_{1t} \ge \pi_{2t}$ **if** both worker 1 and worker 2 pick up jobs at time $t$. What is unclear from your description is whether every worker picks up a job at every time epoch.